# Change the value of the pointer to an object from within the object in java

Tags: java

I have a tree implementation which has `TreeNode` with a field (`Tree myTree`) to the `parent(this)` to check if a `treeNode` belongs to the parent.

When I remove a node(cascade way), I change that value of the treeNode and all of its children to `null` to avoid bad uses (a bit inefficient but required).

Now the question: 
when the treeNode to change is the root, will it be faster to "recreate" the tree (change memory value to a new, change the pointer or similar) to get a new value for "this", instead of changing every single treeNodes value to null.

Something like:

```
this = new Tree<E>();
```

All inside the class tree;

Another problem is that I can't return the value to the outside variable because `remove()` already return the value of the treeNode eliminated.

Comment: `this` can never be assigned. I don't understand the rest. Can you make a small example in code that demonstrates what you're explaining?

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses call by value. Thus you can not change the reference within a object to a new reference that will affect the caller.

Neither any other object using exactly the same reference.